# Preview website without DNS like hostcx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to make a website like HostCX is this possible with Nginx Reverse Proxy and what is needed to achieve this? When the website google.com is entered it should not be checked based on DNS resolution but based on IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a website like HostCX using Nginx Reverse Proxy is certainly possible. Nginx can be a powerful tool for routing incoming requests to different backend servers based on various criteria, including IP address. To achieve the specific behavior you mentioned, where a domain like "google.com" is resolved to an IP address and then routed based on that IP address, you can follow these general steps:

**1. Setting Up Nginx:**

- Ensure you have Nginx installed and configured on your server.

**2. DNS Resolution:**

- You can use a tool like nslookup or Python's socket.gethostbyname to resolve domain names to IP addresses programmatically. For example, in Python:

**Python code:**

```
import socket
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname("google.com")
```

**3. Nginx Configuration**

Create an Nginx configuration file, typically located in /etc/nginx/sites-available/, for your website.
nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourwebsite.com; # Replace with your website's domain

    location / {
        resolver <DNS_SERVER_IP>; # Use a DNS server you trust
        set $backend_ip <IP_ADDRESS>; # Replace with the resolved IP address
        proxy_pass http://$backend_ip;
    }
}
```

In this configuration, replace <DNS_SERVER_IP> with a DNS server's IP address (e.g., Google's DNS server, which is 8.8.8.8), and <IP_ADDRESS> with the resolved IP address of "google.com" or the desired website.

**4. Nginx Reload:**

After creating the configuration file, create a symbolic link to it in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ directory and test the configuration using nginx -t. If the test is successful, reload Nginx to apply the changes:

Bash code:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-config-file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

**5. Testing**

- Now, when you access your website (e.g., "yourwebsite.com"), Nginx will resolve "google.com" to the specified IP address and route requests to that IP address.

Remember to replace "yourwebsite.com" with your actual domain name and ensure that you have DNS resolution and Nginx properly configured on your server. Additionally, note that this approach essentially routes traffic to a specific IP address based on the domain name, but it won't work well for websites hosted on shared IP addresses or CDNs that distribute content across multiple IP addresses.

Comment: I have this but this config is not working?

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name google.local;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $backend_ip 142.251.39.110;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_ip;
    }

}

Comment: Aight but the config u provided appears to be an attempt to create a reverse proxy for the "google.local" domain, resolving it to the IP address 142.251.39.110 and proxying requests to that IP address. However, there are a couple of issues with the configuration that might be causing it not to work as expected.

1. Missing DNS Resolution for "google.local":
2. proxy_pass Directive: make sure IP is still valid. 
3. Server Name: make sure the client has a hosts file entry or can resolve it correctly.
4. nginx syntax: double check ur nginx syntax for errors
5. Please rate my answer ;)

Comment: Okay what should I do then?

Comment: Try: nginx -t  -- Also maybe paste your config files to pastebin or somewhere else to review them, because obviously something is wrong